# postgres inbuilt vs user defined function performance

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have to count the number of bits in postgresql on very large integer columns for which i wrote a postgresql funtion to count the number of bits in an integer.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bitcount(i integer) RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE n integer;
  DECLARE bitCount integer;
BEGIN
  bitCount := 0;

  LOOP
    IF i = 0 THEN
      EXIT;
    END IF;
    i := i & (i-1);
    bitCount:= bitCount+1;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN bitCount;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

but i found one more way to do this using pg's inbuilt functions as well
like

```
SELECT char_length( replace(100::bit(31)::TEXT, '0', ''));
```

so i decided to compare performance of both of the ways
so i used below queries to compare

First

```
SELECT a.n, bitcount(a.n)
from generate_series(1, 100000) as a(n);
```

Second

```
SELECT a.n, char_length( replace(a.n::bit(31)::TEXT, '0', ''))
FROM generate_series(1, 100000) as a(n);
```

I was expecting that First method will outperform the second one
but to my surprise both of them performed almost same. In fact on my machine second one always completed a few seconds faster even with large number of integers.

can anyone explain me why second is almost as fast as first despite of using cast and string operation ?

Comment: The built-in functions are all written in C - a PL/pgSQL function will always be slower. If you write your `bitcount()` function in C, then it will most probably outperform the solution using `char_length()` and casting

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it is because PL/pgSQL is known to be slow.

Write the function in PL/Perl or PL/Python for better performance.